# Push notifications using React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, push-notification

We are developing a mobile application that a user can register and subscribe with a monthly fee, the main function of the app is to notify the users just like messaging app. The notification will be coming from the admin dashboard. Anyone could advise us how to Push Notifications in real time to users both ios and android. We are using React-Native. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would recommend firebase push notifications https://rnfirebase.io/.

Comment: This helps! we need to support multiple devices at a time

Comment: @Michelley: Onesignal is also a good option.https://onesignal.com/.
https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal
It is pretty easy. It has a feature like a tag user property. You can create segments(basically it is group of user based on some criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty popular GitHub repository for creating a notification system with React Native: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification. It has support for both iOS and Android, however, it seems like Android may take more installation effort because it isn't supported by the React Native developers. I would recommend taking an hour or two following the installation instructions, trying it out, and seeing if it is right for your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! We'll definitely try it out.